# How can I know where an error is being caught in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

I am working with a huge code base, there is a function that I am throwing an Error in, However the error is caught somewhere before reaching the top level.
How do I know where the error is getting caught?

Comment: This is highly dependant on the implementation of the packages involved in the bug, but typically when an error and printed, the whole error stack will show up in the console including the source in your code.

Comment: The problem is that the error is not being printed!

Comment: I would suggest that you use some powerful debugger like *visual studio* or *web storm*, with the help of some break points you might be able to trace the flow of the data until you find the problem.

Comment: Just set a breakpoint right before the error is thrown and step into it and it should take you to where it's caught.

Comment: And, you don't need some "powerful" debugger like was previously suggested.  You can just use Chrome - it works great.